# Definition of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am reading linear algebra. I didn't understand in the definition of a linear transformation between two vector spaces why do we take the same field for both domain and Co domain vector spaces? 
Can we replace both fields or one of them by its subfield?

Comment: If it helps: Let $(V,F_1)$ and $(W,F_2)$ be vector spaces such that $F_1$ is a subfield of $F_2$. Then also $(W,F_1)$ is a vector space (over $F_1$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$L(v+w)=L(v)+L(w)$ , fine.  But $L(cv)=cL(v)$ implies that we need to be able to multiply by the same scalars in the domain as in the codomain.  Therefore I think we need the same base field.

Comment: For example if I take superfield for Co domain space still I don't think there will be some problems for this argument. Because c will be there also

Comment: Right.   I noticed that.